# How to understand java class literals?

Tags: java, literals

In JLS 15.8.2, it says

> A class literal is an expression consisting of the name of a class, interface, array, or primitive type, or the pseudo-type void, followed by a `.` and the token `class`.

And in [WIKI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expression_(computer_science)), it says

> An expression in a programming language is a combination of explicit values, constants, variables, operators, and functions...

And I didn't see any operator similar to it in [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/opsummary.html)

I know that `String.class` is an instance of `Class<String>`, I just don't understand why on earth we can write an expression like this.

So what is `.class` really and how to understand this notation?

Comment: For all practical purposes, `String.class` is not _an_ instance of `Class<String>` it is _the_ instance.  Unless you are doing something very tricky, all of the strings in your program should belong to the same class (i.e., to the same `Class<String>` instance).

Comment: There are a lot of annotation (which need static information), which needs a class information and you can give it like that (example TestNG): `@Test(expectedException = BlubException.class)`. And there are other reasons to use `XYZClass.class`. You may get a good answer with more examples.

Comment: I think everyone is misinterpreting the question. As far as I understand, he's asking why this is a valid notation when the list of operators doesn't include `.`.

Comment: As for why, It just _is_.  `Foo.class` has been part of the Java language since the very beginning, same as `a.length` where `a` is an array reference.

Comment: A guess:  The Java designers probably wanted the naked name of a class to be a _type_ expression so that we could write declarations like `String s;`  Allowing the same exact token to stand for a class literal in a different context would have made the formal syntax of the language more complex (harder to write a compiler), so they needed a different syntax to denote a class literal.  How they hit upon _typename_`.class`, I do not know.  I would have suggested `String.getClass()` (i.e., a static method call) if I could have been there at the time.

Comment: @james large: actually, they were introduced in Java1.1, so they are younger than `array.length`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`String.class` is a *primary* expression which does not decompose into operands and operators, but that doesn't stop it from having internal syntactic structure. I am sure you will agree that `"` is not an operator, either, yet `"i am a string"` is a literal expression.

Answer (score 0):

If there were a public field on object `foo` called `bar`, you could address that field with simply `foo.bar`. It's the same thing here - think of it as an implicit public static field called `class`.

Answer (score 0):

The `.` is in fact an operator: it's the "dot operator". It's not mentioned in the official list of operators because.. who knows.

It is however mentioned in [the official tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/usingobject.html):

> Code that is outside the object's class must use an object reference or expression, followed by the dot (.) operator, followed by a simple field name,

Comment: For something to qualifiy for an operator it would have to be used only in the context where its left-hand and right-hand side are _operands_ and an operand must be an expression. So, unofficially we call it an operator, but formally it really isn't one.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik I'm not quite convinced that the left and right side aren't operands. Doesn't the first one access a class and the second a field? I'm not familiar with the Java terminology of the syntax tree but in C#'s Roslyn, those are "SimpleMemberAccessExpression" expressions.

Comment: But i can't find a field name `class`.

Comment: No, `String` is not an expression and `class` is not an expression. You cannot look up a field on something that doesn't even evaluate.

Comment: @ChongYoung: _i can't find a field name class_  That's because it's magic.  It's not a static field.  It's part of the _language_.  The compiler knows what .class means without ever having to look at the class object itself.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax `Foo.class` is a shortcut for `(new Foo()).getClass()` without the memory allocation.  It is useful any time a method wants to receive an instance of `Class<?>` as an argument.

Some examples in the standard library:

- [Collections](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html)
- [Arrays](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html)